# What are the alternatives for searching users using custom fields in Drupal 7?

Tags: entities, users, search

Drupal 7

I would like to be able to search through users by two fields, in this case `name` and `surname` through a single input field and not having to use complete fields. The goal, for a user with `name` field '*John Jo*' and `surname` 'Doe', would be to be able to find him searching '*john j*', '*jo doe*', or '*john doe*' (note the mixture of incomplete fields).

I'm willing to create extra fields if necessary, that's no issue, a colleague told me about the possibility of using [Apache SOLR](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) to index those fields (don't even know if it's possible) but would like to be certain that it's a correct path before embarking on the trip.

Comment: Are you asking if Drupal's SOLR implementation(s) can index field data? If so, then it's a very large "YES"

Comment: @Clive I'm asking if indexing those fields would allow me to search in the way I was exemplifying

Comment: You're asking in the wrong place really; whether SOLR can produce a query of that complexity, straddled over various indices, is a question for the SOLR support forums I'd wager. If you find out that it can, but can't reproduce it with one of the Drupal modules, then a feature request to that module would be appropriate

Comment: You can also use a views combined exposed filter with a "contains" setting.